# How do i stop hibernate search from sniffing the nodes of a non-existent local elastic search server?

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I've created a open search service domain on AWS and i've set the property `hibernate.search.backend.uris` to the address of that domain. Everything works fine, i'm able to index my entity tables and can run search queries against the open search service domain.

Yet for some reason hibernate search still routinely tries to connect to `localhost:9200` in order to perform a node sniffing routine. This obviously doesn't work and the exception `[es_rest_client_sniffer[T#1]] Sniffer - error while sniffing nodes java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information` is thown.

How do i stop hibernate search from performing this futile action? It keeps trying to sniff the nodes every few minutes or so. I've tried setting the fields `hibernate.search.backend.hosts` and `hibernate.search.backend.protocol` instead of `.uris`. But even when i set those properties instead hibernate search still tries to interact with a non-existent elastic search service on `localhost`. I am running hibernate search `6.1.5.Final`. The elastic search version is set to `7.16.3`. Here are all the relevant properties that i set programmatically.

```
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.aws.credentials.type", "static");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.aws.credentials.access_key_id", awsId);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.aws.credentials.secret_access_key", awsKey);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.aws.region", openSearchAwsInstanceRegion);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.aws.signing.enabled", true);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.automatic_indexing.synchronization.strategy", indexSynchronizationStrategy);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.request_timeout", requestTimeout);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.connection_timeout", elasticSearchConnectionTimeout);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.read_timeout", readTimeout);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.max_connections", maximumElasticSearchConnections);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.max_connections_per_route", maximumElasticSearchConnectionsPerRout);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.schema_management.strategy", schemaManagementStrategy);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer", "class:config.EnhancedLuceneAnalysisConfig");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.uris", elasticSearchHostAddress);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.directory.type", "local-filesystem");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.type", "elasticsearch");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.directory.root", luceneAbsoluteFilePath);
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.lucene_version", "LUCENE_CURRENT");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.io.writer.infostream", true);
```

EDIT:

These are all the elastic search related dependencies that my application uses.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch-aws</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Heres the stacktrace,

```
[ERROR] 2022-07-21 14:33:58.402 [es_rest_client_sniffer[T#1]] Sniffer - error while sniffing nodes
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:918) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:299) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:287) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.ElasticsearchNodesSniffer.sniff(ElasticsearchNodesSniffer.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer.sniff(Sniffer.java:209) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer$Task.run(Sniffer.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer$1.run(Sniffer.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    ... 1 more
```

This stacktrace was copied after i had removed `<elasticsearch.version>7.16.3</elasticsearch.version>` so see whether that would solve the problem. If the version is missing hibernate search seems to default to version `7.17.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a while but i finally found the source of the problem.

Apparently `spring boot` has a built-in autoconfiguration class for `Elastic search` called `ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration`. The code in this class is run by default and it initializes a `org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient` that that has a `node sniffer` enabled by default. If no elastic search server is running on localhost this `RestClient` will keep throwing exceptions because there is nothing to connect to.

Because this class is not part of the `hibernate search` java library, settings such as `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.enabled = false` do not influence this `RestClient` or its `Sniffer`.
You can prevent `Spring` from creating this `RestClient` by telling `Spring` not to run `ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration`. This can be done in two ways.

Firstly you can add the following property to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration
```

Second, you can also exclude this autoconfiguration class by adding it as a value to the `exclude` argument of the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. For instance:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude ={ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class}) 
public class MyConfiguration {
```

Comment: That didn't work for me in SB 3.2.0. 
My solution: Replace dependency org.opensearch.client:spring-data-opensearch-starter:1.3.0 
with org.opensearch.client:spring-data-opensearch:1.3.0 (which does not include the Sniffer library and auto-configuration)

Comment: Is this same as for opensearch ?

Comment: @IsuruMaldeniya yes. I'm using opensearch as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search will only enable node discovery (create a sniffer) if [the configuration property `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.enabled` is set to `true`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-configuration-discovery), and by default it's `false`.

If the properties you listed are the only ones you set, then I don't think Hibernate Search is creating this sniffer. The sniffer also doesn't use the URIs you passed to Hibernate Search, so that as well tends to prove the sniffer is not created by Hibernate Search.

If you don't believe me, see by yourself by starting your app in debug mode and putting a breakpoint in [`org.hibernate.search.backend.elasticsearch.client.impl.ElasticsearchClientFactoryImpl#createSniffer`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/120092239cdc1afcfeab4eb18f40570a63caf1c6/backend/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/elasticsearch/client/impl/ElasticsearchClientFactoryImpl.java#L205-L228).

I think you probably have something else in your application creating an Elasticsearch client and a sniffer, and that something else is not completely configured. Try launching your application in debug mode and putting breakpoints in the constructors of `org.elasticsearch.client.sniff.Sniffer`?

Comment: I've checked my pom file but the only elastic search related dependencies that i have are `hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch-aws` and `hibernate-search-mapper-orm`. Could the sniffer be created by the `hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch-aws` library?

Comment: Also, i've tried setting `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.enabled` explicitly to false but that has no effect either

Comment: It does respond to the setting `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.enabled` when i set it to `true` though. In that case i no longer get the 'no connection' error but instead it prints the warning `[es_rest_client_sniffer[T#1]] Sniffer - no nodes to set, nodes will be updated at the next sniffing round` Is enabling this setting expensive? If not i might just set it to true and set `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.refresh_interval` to something really high so that it only sniffs once in a while. I truely have no idea what other dependency could be causing this.

Comment: ok, even if i set `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.enabled` to true i still get the same error every once in a while, regardless of how i set the `hibernate.search.backend.discovery.refresh_interval` property. So the aforementioned settings are completely ignored by whatever is causing this problem. The exception originates from `elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer-7.16.3.jar`. I will put the full stacktrace in my post. I do not have a separate elasticsearch-7.16.3 dependency defined in my pom.xml, the only reference to this ES version that _is_ in my pom.xml is

Comment: <elasticsearch.version>7.16.3</elasticsearch.version>

Comment: I also tried disabling it programmatically with `BackendSettings.backendKey(DISCOVERY_ENABLED, "false");`. This doesn't work either.

Comment: Like I said, just launch your application in debug mode and use breakpoints to determine who creates that sniffer. I don't see any way Hibernate Search could be creating the Sniffer if discovery is disabled. Also, `BackendSettings.backendKey(DISCOVERY_ENABLED, "false");` doesn't make sense, you're passing a property value to a method that builds a property key...

Comment: i found the source of the problem. Spring boot automatically creates a sniffer equiped `RestClient` by default. This `RestClient` instance is unaffected by any `hibernate search` specific properties that are set. I've explained in my answer below how to prevent Spring from creating a RestClient. I found out that you are a member of the hibernate search development team. Could you add the information i provided to the hibernate search documentation for me? This could prevent others from running into the same problem as i have.

Comment: This is a problem you can have regardless of whether you're using Hibernate Search or not. In fact this is purely a problem you're having because you included the Spring Data Elasticsearch dependency. I'm not going to start adding a troubleshooting section dedicated to Spring Data Elasticsearch in the Hibernate Search documentation. I could consider merging a pull request that adds something short and understandable to the documentation to explain something like "Hibernate Search configuration does not affect Spring Data Elasticsearch". Beyond that, others will still have your answer to help.

Comment: no i'm only using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` maven dependency and this library doesn't have spring data elastic search [as a dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.7.1). `ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class` really is part of the [spring boot library](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.13/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.html). But you don't have to add the information, i guess people could just use my answer on stackoverflow as well.

Comment: Ah, well, *that* changes everything. Thanks, I'll add something to the documentation.